# Illustrator: Is there an option to create shared layer styles?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layer-style, graphic-styles

I am just wondering if there is any option in illustrator similar to the shared layer styles in Fireworks.

For example:

I apply a defined color to several objects/elements (Text or Shapes) and if i change that color, it will automatically change on every element that it was applied to.

I hope you know what I am trying to explain here and can help me out with a positiv answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. This is what **Graphic Styles** in Illustrator are designed to do.

More information can be found in Illustrator's Help Files : https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/graphic-styles.html

It may also be beneficial to explore **Symbols** within Illustrator. Symbols are based more upon *specific* artwork than effects, but the use of Symbol Instances can be handy.

More information on Symbols can also be found in the Illustrator help files: https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/symbols.html

Comment: Add to that global colors

Comment: @Scott thanks for your reply! I already know graphic styles, but somehow I can't edit them globally when applied. when I select a graphic style it shows up in my appearence panel. When I try to change the fill-color, it creates automatically a new appearence and doens't update the current graphic style.

Comment: You need to review the help files @SlimMarten There are specific steps to apply styles to objects, then to update styles so changes are reflected on those objects. That isn't an issue with Graphic Styles, it's an issue with *how* you are using the Styles.

Comment: @Scott ... Shame on me, alt + drag.. thank you, I didn't made it to the bottom of the doc: "Replace graphic style attributes.
Alt‑drag (Windows) or Option‑drag (Mac OS) the graphic style you want to use onto the graphic style you want to replace."